# Someone have any examples of how to treat return Json (url) using Modified Java Script Value?

Tags: javascript, json, pentaho, kettle, data-integration

Someone have any examples of how to treat return Json (url) using Modified Java Script Value?
Follow data the I need from url json:

```js
{
"result": {
"data": [
{
"name": "page1",
"period": "dia",
"values": [
{
"value": 4,
"end_time": "2016-03-25"
},
{
"value": 2,
"end_time": "2016-03-26"
},
{
"value": 0,
"end_time": "2016-03-27"
}
],

},
{
"name": "page2",
"period": "dia",
"values": [
{
"value": 22,
"end_time": "2016-03-25"
},
{
"value": 30,
"end_time": "2016-03-26"
},
{
"value": 88,
"end_time": "2016-03-27"
}
],

}
```

I need create rows this data.
Regards,
Santana, Marcos

Comment: It's really not clear what you want to do.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, You right, not need js, only json.
But I have problem.
Getting catch the names, but value and dates do not.
I'm using:
$ .. Date [*]. Name
$ .. Date [*]. Values (the problem is here, it loads the three values (value, end_time) and need only one.
I tried $ .value it gives error and then shows that it has more than one value.

I got it, I used a step select value, split fields and Row Normaliser.

Thanks so much!
Santana, Marcos

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the data you want in the rows this could be achieve better and faster with JSON Input. For instance if you write `$..value` and `$..end_time` in the `Fields` it creates the rows.

If you want to do it in JavaScript (but here is no reason why this cannot be done in JSON Input) here is a sample script to get you started:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
datas = obj.result.data;
for (var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
  var data = datas[i];
  for (var ii = 0; ii < data.values.length; ii++) {
    var value = data.values[ii];
    var row = createRowCopy(getOutputRowMeta().size());
    var idx = getInputRowMeta().size();
    row[idx++] = value.value;
    row[idx++] = value.end_time;
    putRow(row);
  }
}
trans_Status = SKIP_TRANSFORMATION;
```

Remember to add the two values you add to the row to the output fields of the step. value - string and end_time - string.

Comment: this will not work, is ecmascript of pentaho kettle, e4x, do not have JSON.parse function.

Comment: This was tested when I posted the answer, and it worked.

Comment: JSON.parse ? uh! wich version of pentaho are you using?